# Unable to auto fetch MS Form Id in power automate MS Forms response submitted trigger

Tags: power-automate, sharepoint-list, microsoft-forms

I am working on creating a power automate which will create a list item each time new MS form response is submitted by user.

The MS form title 'Employee Survey' has been created by another user has shared that form with my user id and has set me there as a co-owner of the form.
Now when I tried to create an automate flow with 'When a new response is submitted' as trigger , I don't see the dynamic 'Form Id :' value when I click over the form id input box provided.

Can any one guide me why I a unable to get the dynamic form id to select under 'Form Id:' box?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There might be some limitations of MS Forms Connectors for Power Automate.
MS Forms connectors may only work with **organizations accounts**

You can visit [this link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/microsoftforms/#get-response-details) for more information.

How to **Share to collaborate** MS Forms [visit this](https://uaa.teamdynamix.com/TDClient/36/Portal/KB/ArticleDet?ID=79)